# assembly: cannot draw a square in graphic mode

Tags: assembly, graphics, x86, nasm

i wrote that code in asssembly:

```
[bits 16]
[org 0x7c00]

mov ah, 0   ;
mov al, 13h ; set graphic mode
int 10h     ; 

mov cx, sx 
mov dx, sy  
mov ah, 0ch 

colcount:
inc cx
int 10h
cmp cx, hh
jne colcount

mov cx, sx  
inc dx      
cmp dx, ww
jne colcount

;;; vars section
sx dd 0     ;start x position
sy dd 0     ;start y position
hh dd 30    ;height
ww dd 30    ;width

times 510 - ($ - $$) db 0x0
dw 0xaa55
```

i expected this code to draw a square at the top left corner of the screen but it draw only a rect in the middle.
I don't know where is the problem.
I use nasm as compiler, there aren't any error message.
I took a part of that code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23723904/how-to-draw-a-square-int-10h-using-loops), thanks [YonBruchim](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3337546/yonbruchim).

Comment: `mov cx, sx` will set `cx` to memory address of the first byte of the dword defined by `dd 0` in `;;; vars section`. I.e. it will be something like `cx = 0x7C20` (just guessing the size of the code ahead of "vars"). To read the value 0 from memory, you have to mark that as memory access, like `mov cx,[sx]` ... same goes with `cmp cx, hh`, etc... It would work as expected if you would assemble it with MASM or TASM (but then the `[bits 16]` is NASM syntax, which would not work in MASM/TASM). You need to pick correct syntax for the assembler you are using.

Comment: Also the jump `jne colcount`, when the zero flag will be set ("equal" is true), the CPU will read next byte in memory as instruction and try to execute it. The `sx dd 0` will be decoded as `add [bx+si],al`, modifying some unrelated piece of memory targetted by current values in `bx` and `si`. If you are trying to write test bootloader, where you want to observe final result, you can use some infinite loop like `jmp $-2`. And your current code is not in any way related to bootloaders, so why don't you practice assembly basics in more friendly environment, with some debugger.

Comment: You can try for example code from this answer, which is resolving not only square drawing, but also animation, and in bootloader, with NASM (although I never truly tested it myself as bootloader, just as DOS program): https://stackoverflow.com/a/42946600/4271923 (but it's not using BIOS services to draw pixels, it writes to VRAM directly, so it may be confusing for you a bit, if you will try to decipher how it works, will take a bit more effort)